# Declaration inside the loop will maintain the memory space or create multiple space?

Tags: vb.net, loops

Consider the method which i written as a sample of this question:

```
Public Sub Myfun()
   Dim loopcount As Integer
   For loopcount = 0 To 1000
    Dim x as integer = 2
    x * = loopcount 
    ListBox1.Items.Add (x)
   Next 
End Sub
```

My question is that this type of declaration will create **how much of memory space for** `x`.
how it is being identified if it creates 1000 separate spaces with the same name as `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `x` is a local variable albeit declared inside a loop and this affects its visibility not the memory space occupied by that variable.

Looking at the IL code generated when you remove the ListBox1 object it is pretty clear what happens

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    // store 0 on top of stack
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // load first local variable (loopcount) with top of stack
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.2    // store 2 on top of stack
IL_0003:  stloc.1     // load second local variable (x) with top of the stack
IL_0004:  ldloc.1     // store x on top of the stack
IL_0005:  ldloc.0     // store loopcount on top of the stack
IL_0006:  mul.ovf     // multiply with overflow check the last two integers on stack
IL_0007:  stloc.1     // store the top of stack in second local variable (x)
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     // following is the logic of the for .... loop
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_000A:  add.ovf     
IL_000B:  stloc.0     
IL_000C:  ldloc.0     
IL_000D:  ldc.i4      E8 03 00 00 
IL_0012:  ble.s       IL_0002  // Repeat the loop from IL_002
```

Comment: Would the answer be much different if x was a New Object?

Comment: if _Object_ is a reference type, then every loop will call new and that will allocate a different area of memory. The previous object, if it is no more referenced, will become eligible for garbage collection and freed _sooner or later_. By itself, the local variable that holds the reference to the object is still a variable created on the stack and there are no multiple copies of it